# Install Maven in Eclipse without plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, m2e

Is it possible to install Maven in Eclipse without additional plugins like m2e? I just want the "pure" version to have the control using the command line and also to learn how to use it myself.
I have already followed these steps: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Windows, now I need to "integrate" it in Eclipse.

Thank you!

Comment: latest version of eclipse comes with maven integrated, in case you are starting fresh use latest one

Comment: @VD': I don't want to use any plugins like m2e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, m2e *is* the Maven integration for Eclipse. *Virtually everything* in Eclipse is a plug-in, there is no other way to integrate a tool or technology.

If you want to learn Maven via command-line, you can just open a shell in the folder that contains your project(s). Alternatively, you can use an integrated shell plug-in for Eclipse. Here are some I've used in the past:

- [Wicked Shell](http://www.wickedshell.net/)
- [Easy Shell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell)
- [More in the Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/shell)